# c++ sqrt() calculation assistance

Tags: c++

So I'm studying c++ from the book ((C++ without fear)). and there's a code I didn't understand. I need to know how the code works. my problem is in the loop, I understand how it works, but I didn't understand how would it work with adding 1 to i. (EVEN WITH COMMENTS).

```
 #include <iostream>
 #include <cmath>
 using namespace std;
 int main() {
     int n = 0; // Number to test for prime-ness
     int i = 2; // Loop counter
     bool is_prime = true; // Boolean flag...
     // Assume true for now.
     // Get a number from the keyboard.
     cout << "Enter a number and press ENTER: ";
     cin >> n;
     // Test for prime by checking for divisibility
     // by all whole numbers from 2 to sqrt(n).
     while (i <= sqrt(n)) {
         if (n % i == 0) { // If i divides n,
             is_prime = false; // n is not prime.
         }
         ++i; // Add 1 to i.
     }
     // Print results
     if (is_prime) {
         cout << "Number is prime." << endl;
     }   
     else 
     {
         cout << "Number is not prime." << endl;
     }
     return 0;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the time to read [The Tour](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) and refer to the material from the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) what and how you can ask here.

Answer (score 0):

Adding 1 to `i` is simply to move on to test the *next* number the next time round the loop to test if it divides `n`. `++i` is simply the prefix increment operator being invoked. Postfix `i++;` *could* be used here for the same effect, as could `i = i + 1;`, but since there exist some cases where prefix increment is faster than the alternatives (not the case here) it's usually a good habit to use prefix increment always unless you have a specific reason not to do so.

Comment: (from my understanding). if I entered 16. the square root is 4. The first time remainder is zero. If it adds 1 to i, the remainder would be 1. It would be prime.

Comment: @MS01 huh? If you enter 16, yes, the square root is 4, so `if (n % i == 0)` will be true and it will set `is_prime = false;`. The stupid code will then carry on testing more numbers - even though it could just `break` the loop there - but that won't change the value of `is_prime`, so it will, in the end, still report 16 as being *not* prime. Not the most *efficient* primality test, but it does work.